# JavaFX - drawing (snake) in a loop

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Currently, I'm playing around with JavaFX as I'm writing a Snake game for my Java Fundamentals class final project. I'm not that new to creating simple games with animations as I've made a bit of them using PyGame module and SDL in C. Anyway, now I'm quite struggling with understanding the correlations of some objects in JavaFX, especially when combined with SceneBuilder's FXMLs.

I just can't understand how to create an equivalent of gameloop I used to implement in PyGame or SDL. What I want to do with the code below is to enter the gameloop as soon as a new Game object is created and draw the state of the game continuously on the gameCanvas created in the SceneBuilder. I think I can easily manage all the stuff later, but I just can't sort it out how to create a legit bond between the FXML canvas and the gameloop I want to run.

**GameController.java**

```
public class GameController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

@FXML
private Canvas gameCanvas;

@Override
public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenPage) {
    // THIS IS FOR SCENE MANAGEMENT CONCEPT

}
```

**Game.java**

```
public class Game implements Runnable {

    public static final int EASY = 1,
                            MEDIUM = 2,
                            HARD = 3;

    int difficultyLevel, score = 0;
    Snake snake;
    Food food;
    boolean isRunning = true;


    public void setLevelEasy() {
        difficultyLevel = EASY;
    }

    public void setLevelMedium() {
        difficultyLevel = MEDIUM;
    }

    public void setLevelHard() {
        difficultyLevel = HARD;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {

        }

    }

}



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   

}
```

Comment: [Introduction to JavaFX for Game Development](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835) and [Getting Started with JavaFX Game Programming](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/getting-started-with-javafx-game-programming-for-java-programmers/37201/view.html)

Comment: See http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops and http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx (short version: use an `AnimationTimer`).

Answer (score 0):

You cant use FXML file to create new scene. Use this instead

```
public class Screen extends Application implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage primaryStage )
    {
        Pane pane = new Pane ();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,500,300);
        primaryStage.setScene ( scene );
        primaryStage.show ();
    }

    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        launch ();
    }
}
```

anything you want to add goes to pane element your canvas etc.
and by the way make dificulty enum not int like

```
enum {easy,medium,hard}
```

that way nobody can set dificulty level to something does not exist.